# computed v-model in select tag in Vuejs2

Tags: vue-component, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component whose markup is

```
<select id="create-claim-start_date" type="text" class="form-control" v-model="startPeriod">
                                  <option value="0">January</option>
                                  <option value="3">April</option>
                                  <option value="6">July</option>
                                  <option value="8">October</option>
                                </select>
```

where `startPeriod` is a computed property

```
..........
data() {
   return { form: { claim_start_date: null } }
},
computed: {
      startPeriod: {
        get: function(){
          var d = window.moment();
          return d.get('month');
        },
        set: function(p) {
          var dt = window.moment()
          dt.set(p,'month');
          this.form.claim_start_date = dt.get('YYYY-mm-dd');
        }
      }
    }
   ........
```

Can I use a computed property as a model? Would the computed property trigger the update of a data property?

Comment: Please consider about using watchers instead.

Comment: watcher on the computed or the data ?

Comment: Computed properties are reactive by itself, so probably you won't need to watch computed property.

Comment: Computed property change will change related data property referred to in the `set` function, but use computed for `v-model` isn't a good idea as `computed` and `data` are probably treated differently inside vue.

Comment: @PanJunjie潘俊杰 that is an interesting comment...please explain?

Comment: For the first part, you can see [here in the doc](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#computed). The second part is just my guess but I feel it's reasonable. I've never seen doc or anyone's example using a `computed` as `v-model`, you should be able to refactor your intention to `v-model="someDataProp"` with the help of `watch` and so on...

Comment: @PanJunjie潘俊杰 thanks for the insight I believe I used the computed vs the watcher because i needed to get and set which IMHO seems double the work using a watch and method to set the data. Thought it would be good on energy too

Answer (score 2):

If you need to update the value of `claim_start_date` when the select changes you can use a watcher.

Here is an example:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    startPeriod: '0',
    form: {
      claim_start_date: 'defaultValue'
    }
  },

  watch: {
    startPeriod: function(newValue, oldValue) {
      this.form.claim_start_date = "new value " + newValue;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.0/moment.min.js"></script>   

<div id="app">
  <select id="create-claim-start_date" type="text" class="form-control" v-model="startPeriod">
    <option value="0">January</option>
    <option value="3">April</option>
    <option value="6">July</option>
    <option value="8">October</option>
  </select>

  {{form.claim_start_date}}

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you may be taking that value and are going to use it later to create a Moment object...might it just be easier to use a Date/Moment object for the option values to begin with?

You can bind javascript values (i.e. objects) to the options values. You may need to adjust how you are setting the dates since we don't know the year/day.

```
<select id="create-claim-start_date" class="form-control" v-model="startPeriod">
    <option :value="moment('2016-01-01')">January</option>
    <option :value="moment('2016-04-01')">April</option>
    <option :value="moment('2016-07-01')">July</option>
    <option :value="moment('2016-10-01')">October</option>
</select>
```